# Rails AB testing with "split" gem: Negative numbers on non-finished...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ab-testing

I'm using split gem on rails.  usage is quite simple:

some_signin_view_file.erb:

```
<% signin_mode = ab_test( 'log in style','LogIn_ATest','LogIn_BTest' )%> 
.
.
Do something according to signin_mode...
```

and
some_post_signin_controller_file.rb:

```
finished("log in style", :reset=> FALSE)
```

Did one simple test with no problems.
However, my second test yield negative numbers on the non-finished columns, and only on the first experiment (marked as control).

How can it be negative...? Am i missing something?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `:reset => false` option there is nothing to stop the user from completing the same conversion again which currently counts towards the totals.

I suspect the desired behaviour when using `:reset => false` is that the user should not be able to increment the completion counter any more?

Comment: Even with :reset => false, the negative numbers continue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem without setting :reset => false. In other words, by accepting the default value of true. I ran a test with 2 choices and got the following values: A: 251 participants, -1214 non-finished, B: 235 participants, 111 non-finished.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a possible workaround is to use the reset data button (worked in 1 out of 1 cases... :^).
Apparently some issue with initial data...

HTH someone...

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. It worked only because the problematic case didn't reproduce at that time. See Andrew Nesbitt answer instead.